# ibuffer: how to wrap a column?

Tags: display, ibuffer

One of my ibuffer entries looks like this :

```
Readme.txt<somepa...  some_path_that_is_actually_super_duper_mega_giga_long_like_way_too_long/Readme.txt
```

This spills over the fringe and I can't read the end of the path.

I would like to see something like:

```
Readme.txt<somepa...  some_path_that_is_actually_super_duper_
                      mega_giga_long_like_way_too_long/Readme.txt
```

where I can wrap the text per column.

If I use `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` , I get :

```
Readme.txt<somepa...  some_path_that_is_actually_super_duper_
mega_giga_long_like_way_too_long/Readme.txt
```

Which is unuseable because i cannot tell where the next ibuffer entry begins.

How could I do this?

Comment: Not what you are asking for, but works for me: `C-e` to go to the end and `C-a` to go back to the beginning.

Comment: it's quite annoying because it requires the cursor to be on the correct line already.

Comment: i love how i run into problems nobody cares about